# Unknown USB Add/remove program entries

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall

I have the following entries in my Windows XP Professional *Add/Remove Programs* window:

- **USB Storage Driver**. Registry uninstall entry details:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\GENEUIDE]
>   "DisplayName"="USB Storage Driver"
>   "UninstallString"="DelUIDrv.exe"

- **Genesys USB Mass Storage Device**. Registry uninstall entry details:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{B4BF87C8-3EEC-4774-82A2-584F109187B1}]
>   "UninstallString"="RunDll32
>   C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\INSTAL~1\engine\6\INTEL3~1\Ctor.dll,LaunchSetup
>   \"C:\Program Files\InstallShield
>   Installation
>   Information\{B4BF87C8-3EEC-4774-82A2-584F109187B1}\Setup.exe\"
>   " "DisplayName"="Genesys USB Mass
>   Storage Device" "LogFile"="C:\Program
>   Files\InstallShield Installation
>   Information\{B4BF87C8-3EEC-4774-82A2-584F109187B1}\setup.ilg"

Any idea what those are? A simple google search doesn't reveal much...

Would it be safe to uninstall them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be safe to uninstall them ?

No, these are drivers which allow USB flash drive to be used as a hot-pluggable mass storage device ( similar to hard drives).

> Genesys USB Mass Storage Device

Are you sure it's Genesys and not **Generic**

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, see my edit

Comment: You have one of these device? http://www.atechflash.com/products%20AFT.html

Comment: No, can't say that I do...